# JavaScript DOM: Неопределяется переменная через document.getElementByID().value;

Tags: javascript, dom

Суть задачи: по числу, введённое пользователем, выводится соответсвующе число маршрутов в виде № маршрутного такси(значение опеределённое), описание данного маршрута (например начальная и конечная остановки) и в конце кнопка(событий не имеет). Попробовал реализовать через наведение курсора мыши на слово "n маршрут:", что бы потом соответсвующие данные в текстовых формах появлялись, но к сожалению, перменной не присваивается значение по id. Объясните пожалуйста в чём ошибка и как eё устранить?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.forms.z.addEventListener('submit', zFormSubmit); 
}); 
function zFormSubmit(e) {
var value = e.value;

  e.preventDefault(); 
  for (let el of this.querySelectorAll('.str-label'))

 el.remove(); 
  
  for ( var strHtml = '<label class="str-label" >№       Описание</label>', i = 0; i < +this.count.value; i++){ 
    strHtml += `
      <label class="str-label" id="slabel" value = "${i}">
   ${i+1}  маршрут :
        <input name="marsh${i}" id="marsh${i}" type="text" value="${i}" onmousemove="marshChange(this)">
        <input name="marsh${i}" id="marsh${i}" type="text" value="${i}" onmousemove="marshChangeOpisan(marshChange(this))">
      </label>
   
    `;
  if(i == Number(this.count.value)-1){
   strHtml += `<button type="submit"  name="create">Cохранить</button>`;
  }
 }
  this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', strHtml); 
}

function marshChange(el) {
var znachenie = document.getElementById(el).value;
switch(znachenie)
{
 case "0": return document.getElementById(el).value = 215;
 
 
default:return document.getElementById(el).value = '№ маршрута неопределён';
}
}

function marshChangeOpisan(el) {
var value = document.getElementById(el).value;
switch(value)
{
 case 215: return document.getElementById(el).value = 'Ул Валади 42, 30 Сидней';
  
default:return document.getElementById(el).value = '№ маршрута неопределён';
}
}
```

```css
body, input, button { font: 16px sans-serif; }
#z { width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 8px 16px; text-align: center; box-shadow: 0 3px 9px 0 #0002; }
#str-count { width: 40px; }
.str-label { display: block; margin: 0 24px; line-height: 1.5em; text-align: left; }
.str-label:hover { color: #070; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<form id="z" name="z">
<label>введите количество маршрутов:</label>
<!--<input id="cb-count" name="count" type="number" min="1" max="20" placeholder="1..20" required>-->
<input type="text" id="str-count" placeholder="1..20" name="count" required/>
<button type="submit"  name="create">Создать</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы передаете в функцию элемент - `onmousemove="marshChange(this)"`, а в коде думаете, что это `id`:

```
function marshChange(el) {
  // var znachenie = document.getElementById(el).value; - неправильно
  var znachenie = el.value;
  ...
```

Но логика действий в этой функции от меня все равно ускользает :).